# Manage a response to GET request Android

Tags: android, http, servlets, get, response

I have an app android that send a get request to a servlet mounted on Tomcat. I would servlet generate an html page as response to the get request.

This is my get request code. 
How can I manage the response for my goal?

```
try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
      URI getURL = new URI("http://192.168.1.100:8080/MyServlet?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2);
      Log.i("QUERY",getURL.getQuery());
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
      HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
      HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
      if (resEntityGet != null) { 
          Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
     }

} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is your issue???

Comment: I want to generate (as response) an html(or php) page in my app from my java servlet